# Is it necessary to know the spin state of a particle to find the relative branching ratios?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics

I have this problem: $\Sigma^{*0}$ has an isospin state of $|10>$. Assume it can only decay to the final states $\Sigma^+\pi^-,\Sigma^0\pi^0,$ and $\Sigma^-\pi^+$. I need to find the relative branching ratio for the three modes. I'm having a really hard time figuring out what to do. A lot of what I'm finding on the internet goes way over my head. I'm assuming that I need to find the total isopsin of the final state decays, but what do you do once you have that? Is it an inner product of the each spin state to get a probability of each decay?

Comment: Is your decaying particle the lightest spin 3/2 such? You are using nonstandard notation and need to pin the strange baryon down by its mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the isospin of the final state, it's the same as the isospin of the initial state, i.e.$|1,0>$, as you say. That's assuming the decay goes through the strong interaction, which it does.
The $\Sigma$ and the $\pi$ both have isospin 1, and the 3 different $+,-,0$ states have $I_3$ values of +1,-1, and 0. $I_3$ must be conserved, as it is in all 3 cases, as 0=+1-1, 0+0, and -1+1. The total isospin is 1+1, which can be I=0, 1 or 2 (as these combine just like angular momentum). So you just need to know how much of the 3 states
$|I^1,I^2,I^1_3,I^2_3> = |1,1,1,-1>, |1,1,0,0>$ and $|1,1,-1,1>$ is in $|I=1,I_3=0>$ (as opposed to $2,0>$ or $|0,0>$). These numbers are given by the Clebsch-Gordon coefficients, which you can look up.  (For more info see any description of CG coefficients and remember the fact that you're dealing with isospin not physical spin doesn't matter.)

Hint: there is a surprise in the answer. This is a nice example.